# Simple Consensus with Timeouts

Tags: algorithm, consensus

There are `n` participants and each participant has a timeout that could fire at any time before or in the process of consensus. Participants are in a distributed setting where partitions and failures can happen.

All participants can start with a value `0` or `1` (or `true`/`false`). If any participant starts with `0` or any participant's timeout expires before reaching consensus, all participants must decide `0`. Otherwise, all participants must decide `1`.

I've gone through several iterations of a simple consensus protocol inspired or similar to the [Ben-Or consensus protocol](https://cnitarot.github.io/courses/ds_Fall_2016/505_consensus.pdf) but can't seem to find a solution.

The key differences between the Ben-Or protocol and this setting are:

1. Presence of timeout
2. Not randomized: If any are zero, then all should decide zero. If any timeout, then all should decide zero.

An example (inspired by Ben-or) for this highly simplified setting:

```
x = True or False
while x or timeout not expired:
  broadcast report=True
  wait for all other participants' reports until timeout
  if all reports are True and received all reports:
    decide True
  otherwise
    decide False
```

Key thing to prove: If a process `p` decides `True`, all other processes `q` decide `True`

I might be missing some key impossibility theory here. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Randomization is how Ben-Or escapes the Fischer–Lynch–Paterson impossibility result for deterministic consensus algorithms in unreliable networks. I think F–L–P basically applies to this setting unless you intentionally run out the clock each time and return 0 everywhere.

Comment: Thanks - I think FLP impossibility makes sense. What do you mean by "unless you intentionally run out the clock each time and return 0 everywhere"? Do you mean that FLP applies in _all_ instances of this problem that does not result in all participants timing out or choosing 0/False?

Comment: @fpes FLP requires bivalent states -- states where the consensus outcome can be either 0 or 1 depending on how the execution goes. A protocol that always returns 0 after waiting would technically be in compliance with your spec but not satisfy the precondition for impossibility.